saxonche, Python and filename encodings
from saxonche import PySaxonProcessor

with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as proc:
    xsltproc = proc.new_xslt30_processor()
    xml = proc.parse_xml(xml_file_name="Ä.xml")

gives me
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\m3\zml2lido\test\minimal.py", line 5, in <module>
    xml = proc.parse_xml(xml_file_name="Ä.xml")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "python_saxon\saxonc.pyx", line 868, in saxonche.PySaxonProcessor.parse_xml
saxonche.PySaxonApiError: Unable to resolve <Ã„.xml> into a Source. Line number: -1

Any ideas how I can convince saxon to accept filenames involving characters outside of ascii or in utf8 respectively?
Thank you!
EDIT: This is Saxon 12.4.2 on Windows 10.

Is that Saxon 12.4.2, the latest version?

It is a known issue, as a workaround use e.g. xml_file_name=Path(f'Ä.xml').absolute().as_uri() with an from pathlib import Path

Issue is filed under https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/6353.

Cool! Many thanks for super quick answer.

This should be fixed in today's release of 12.5 https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/
